# How to set filepath from db in Edit Form in php

Tags: php, html, image, forms, file-upload

How can I do that when I use Image on a Edit Form? In this code value attribute not working.

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <label>Upload passport Size (3:4) Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="passport_image" value = "<?php echo $passport_image; ?> " >

    <input type="submit" name="submit_button" value="SUBMIT">
</form>
```

Comment: Do you mean "how to show the current image path in the `Edit Form`?"

Comment: Not Exactly. In edit form when I try to re-submit the form, I have to re-upload images. Is that have a solution?

Comment: You should check how different websites do the UI for profile editing with images, and see what you prefer. As far as I know, there are 2 prevalent options - 1. A separate form for the image edit; 2. The image is shown in the form, but only if the user uploads another image you update the image.

Answer (score 0):

input type file doesn't have value attribute..for displaying image you need to use img tag and give path as:<img src='foldername/'. />

Comment: When I try to submit re-submit the form, I have to re-upload images. Is that have a solution?

Comment: if (($images)) {
            $img_update = "update products set image='$images' where pid=$id";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $img_update);
        }
    } else {  //you can use whole insert query here                                            
                  $qry1 = "insert into products (image) values('$images')";
    }    Using this if you dont upload image in edit the previous one remains same..just put your variables in code and try it works

Comment: BUT IN THAT WAY CAN I GIVE A OPTION TO UPDATE THE PIC ALSO?